# How to CREATE Store Procedures in MySql via C# code

Tags: c#, mysql

I am building a program in c# which execute code from sql files of MYSQL. That sql files create a store procedure like:

```
DELIMITER **
USE MyDB**

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_msstudy_Update**


Create Procedure XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
(
    _cad varchar(250)
)

Begin
    SET @dSQL = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', 'mytable',' ADD createdon DATETIME DEFAULT now() NOT NULL');         
    PREPARE stmt FROM @dSQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;      
End
**

DELIMITER ;
```

I have a function which read the lines. obiously in the loop I set some code like

```
line += readedline + "\n";
```

Finally I execute the code with: `ExecuteNonQuery` of `MysqlCommand`. the connection and everything is working but when I execute the sql to create  store procedure give me a syntax error:

```
 C:\PROYECTOS\DB\MySQL\97 xxxx .sql: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_msstudy_Update 
 Create Procedure XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' at line 2
```

My C# code to call the string after read sql is:

```
MySqlConnection conn = null;
            MySqlCommand cmd = null;

            var connectionstring = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=root;";
            try
            {

                using (conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (cmd = new MySqlCommand(mysqlsql, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                    conn.Close();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {

                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
```

to read sql file I use:

```
private string LeerFichero(string sqlfile, bool sp)
{
    string res = "";
    string line;
    try
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(sqlfile);

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            res += line + "\n";
        }
        file.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Could you help me please?

I changed the procedure, new error is giving me. I got to jump the DROP error but now is giving me:

```
C:\PROYECTOS\DB\MySQL\99.sysauditoria.SP.sql: Parameter '@dSQL' must be defined.
```

Comment: Hi @David. Does this SQL work without problem if you run it directly on the DB, not from C#?

Comment: I know, but my question is for c#, read question again please. I have a serveral files and I am building an automatic process.

Comment: I have read the question. Are you saying it works fine directly on the DB? If it doesn't work there, it won't work when called from C#. Also you need to show the C# code, not just which commands you are using.

Comment: wait I write my calling code

Comment: It's been a long time since I've had to do this, but don't you need a semi-colon at the end of `DROP PROCEDURE`?  It does in the MySQL shell and would explain the error message.

Comment: I was testing with the adding and take out semicolon at end of `drop procedure`and the rest of sql code, failed me anyway

Comment: I got jump DROP error now is giving me dSQL is undeclared, see in my question, I added new information...

Comment: You need to declare `dSQL`. Something like `DECLARE dSQL VARCHAR;`, depending on exactly what you need.

Comment: declaring dsql I found an error with my answer, I hacve to find a solution working always, I am not sure (I am new in mysql) if @dSQL is a temporal variable and I think it is not necessary declare when you use with instruction PREPARE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for what I was looking for:

```
MySqlScript script = new MySqlScript(conn, query);
script.Delimiter = "$$";
script.Execute();
```

where query I will set my sql file as string. Store procedure created right with this system.